# Как передать данные в функцию

Tags: веб-программирование, golang

Как передать pageId в функцию editExGroup, в момент вызовая ее в качестве аргумента для HandleFunc(вторая строка)?

```
pageId := '123'

http.HandleFunc("/admin/menu/ex_groups_"+pageId, editExGroup)

func editExGroup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(PageId)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью только средств стандартной библиотеки:

```golang
numberRE := regexp.MustCompile(`ex_groups_([0-9]+)`)
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fullID := path.Base(r.URL.Path)
    matches := numberRE.FindStringSubmatch(fullID)
    if len(matches) != 2 {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    pageID := matches[1]
    log.Println(pageID)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать функцию, которая вернет http.HandlerFunc и в эту функцию передать аргумент pageID

```
// ...
pageID := "123"

http.HandleFunc("/admin/menu/ex_groups_"+pageId, editExGroup(pageID))
// ...
func editExGroup(PageID string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(PageID)
    }
}
```